# How can I insert the value of a variable in a throw statement?

Tags: sql-server

Here's the code I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_test_status]
    @TestStatusId INT OUTPUT,
    @UserTestId INT,
    @UserId     INT
AS
    SELECT * FROM UserTest WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId;
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1)
        THROW 50004,'User Test' + @UserTestId + 'Could not find an existing test to start',1
```

I am getting a syntax error in the throw line. Can someone give me some advice on this?

Comment: build the string before `THROW` and then use it. 
 `DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(300) = CONCAT('User Test' ,@UserTestId ,'Could not find an existing test to start');

 THROW 50004,@Message ,1`

Comment: @ughai - this worked good. Can you add as an answer. Thank you

Comment: you already an answers which is similar to my comment. you can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to declare a nvarchar variable, then store the text u want and use it.

```
Eg : Declare @msg nvarchar(200)
set @msg = 'User Test' + @UserTestId + 'Could not find an existing test to start'
THROW 50004,@msg,1
```

Answer (score 2):

From [THROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee677615(v=sql.110).aspx)

THROW statement does not allow for substitution parameters in the message parameter ,The message parameter does not accept `printf` style formatting.

```
See Example C from the link.
```